# Reading from an Excel (xlsx) file using Apache POI library throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi, tomcat7

I 'm building a JSP web application using Eclipse IDE. The web application loads without issue on tomcat server ver 7. We got a new requirement to read from xls and xlsx file. So we have used Apache POI library (4.1.2) to implement this as follows: I have taken out other codes as they are not relevant for this post

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(args[0]));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); //<- This is where the exception occurs

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
```

But when executing we are getting the below exception. I have tried googling but didn't find relevant help. Can you please assist?

```html
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UploadEstimates] in context with path [/AD] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.ClassLoaderResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoaderResourceLoader.java:33)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.getLoaderStream(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2249)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1522)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.initFromHeader(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:185)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sD023D6490046BA0250A839A9AD24C443.TypeSystemHolder.loadTypeSystem(Unknown Source)
at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sD023D6490046BA0250A839A9AD24C443.TypeSystemHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:775)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:684)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:288)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:342)
at com.MyClient.AD.util.UploadEstimateUT.start(UploadEstimateUT.java:85)
at com.MyClient.AD.util.UploadEstimates.doPost(UploadEstimates.java:107)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1195)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is how I referenced the POI files:
MyProject -> Right Click -> Build Path -> Configure Built Path -> Libraries tab and added the following jars

[image]

And this is how I execute the application
Run -> Run Configuration... -> Classpath tab -> Making sure all jar files are referenced here including Apache POI's -> Apply and/or Run.

[image]

---

**Update 1 (28-Feb-2020)**

I tried the same code (that reads from excel using POI library) as java application and it worked as expected.

Another thing I noted when debugging the JSP web application is that the control is transferred directly to the finally block instead of the general Exception block. Not sure why.

---

**Update 2 (03-Mar-2020)**

I configured the project in my colleagues system who also has Eclipse IDE but with Tomcat server version 9.0.31 and it worked in his machine.

Then I installed Tomcat server version 9.0.31 and configured the project from a separate workspace but when executing I face the same exception. I'm not able to understand what could the difference.

We both are using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers. Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200

---

**Update 3 (06-Mar-2020)**

magicmn, I get the below exception after updating to factory method

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UploadEstimates] in context with path [/AD] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.ClassLoaderResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoaderResourceLoader.java:33)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.getLoaderStream(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2249)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1522)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.initFromHeader(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sD023D6490046BA0250A839A9AD24C443.TypeSystemHolder.loadTypeSystem(Unknown Source)
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sD023D6490046BA0250A839A9AD24C443.TypeSystemHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:775)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:684)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:327)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:295)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:276)
    at com.MyClient.AD.util.UploadEstimateUT.start(UploadEstimateUT.java:90)
    at com.MyClient.AD.util.UploadEstimates.doPost(UploadEstimates.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the FileStream is not null?

Comment: Please share contents of args[] array

Comment: Yes @ChadNC, the filestream is not null.

Comment: @shihabudheenk, args[0] holds the path of the file like C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\wtpwebapps\\MyWebProject\\excel\\myexcel.xlsx

Comment: Friends, I have some update (Update 1 added in the main thread) on this issue. Please see if that can help you

Comment: Which exception are you catching in exception block?

Comment: @shihabudheenk, first catch is for IOException and second is for Exception. The block is like 
try
{
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(args[0]));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);//<--Exception here

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//more code block removed for clarity
}
catch (IOException ioe) 
{
ioe.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Friends, I have some more update (Update 2 added in the main thread) on this issue. Please see if that can help you narrow down my issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your file doesn't contain any unnecessary characters out of headers? [Like this](http://prntscr.com/rbe87s) . That can cause NullPointerException

Comment: @EdgarKhachatryan, no it doesn't. It's a simple and valid xlsx file. Also, this works in my colleague machine with same excel file as well.

Comment: The stacktrace for SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:2249 and ClassLoaderResourceLoader.java:33 seem to be from different XmlBeans jars. Please check your tomcat installation (e.g. .../ext directory) for further XmlBeans jars - maybe it's called xbean*.jar on some legacy/left-over path.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eclipse but I find it extremely suspicious to add all those jars to Bootstrap Entries! They should go to the WEB-INF\lib directory of your app and nowhere else.

Comment: Hi kiwiwings, I downloaded POI 4.1.2 and only included the jars from this zip file. I'm using/upgraded to Tomcat 9.0.31 server and I don't see /ext directory or anything like xbeans*.jar kind of file in the tomcat home directory.

Comment: Please use the below code to see jar locations. System.out.println(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.ClassLoaderResourceLoader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());

System.out.println(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullPointerException is thrown at line 33 of [ClassLoaderResourceLoader](https://github.com/apache/xmlbeans/blob/trunk/src/typeimpl/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/ClassLoaderResourceLoader.java). The line is:

```
return _classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
```

Which means that _classLoader is null. _classLoader is passed to the constructor.

The ClassLoaderResourceLoader object is created at line 182 of [SchemaTypeSystemImpl](https://github.com/apache/xmlbeans/blob/trunk/src/typeimpl/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java):

```
_classloader = indexclass.getClassLoader();
...
_resourceLoader = new ClassLoaderResourceLoader(_classloader);
```

Which means that _classloader is null, which means that indexclass.getClassLoader() is null.

When can getClassLoader() return null? The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--) says:

> Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class
>   loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this
>   class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader.

Bootstrap? Does it ring a bell? Yes, you put all your jars in the Bootstrap Entries, which means that they are loaded by the bootstrap class loader. As I said in a comment (which you seem to have ignored), the correct location for jars is the WEB-INF\lib directory of the application. So just put them in there and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried posting a comment but my rank does not allow me to do so. This is not an answer(so please don't be harsh) but it is what I would've done in your case(I have been working with java and excel files for the last month and I am quite good).

```
File myFile=new File(args[0]);
if(myFile==null)System.out.println("my file is null");else System.out.println("my file is NOT null");
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(args[0]));
```

You can post your results and I will take a stab at it.

Comment: thank you looking into my issue. I added the null check code and debugged the application. The control came to non-null area and the console window  displayed "my file is NOT null". Just like i mentioned in my original post that the same code works in my colleague's machine but not mine. Not sure what is the difference.

Comment: Hi Hemant. Got it. I have been reading up on https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-load-resources-from-classpath-in-java-example.html and have a suggestion. Try removing the absolute path to your file and use a relative one and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Sherma234, no matter whatever virtual path I try, I always get java.io.FileNotFoundException: \excel\123.xlsx. But I think locating file is not the issue. Because even when I hardcode to an existing file, the exception stays as posted in my original request.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure upload is finished before you try to read file?
because from stacktrace:
at com.MyClient.AD.util.UploadEstimateUT.start(UploadEstimateUT.java:85)
it's on start of upload

Comment: Hi wikprim, Yes, i checked and see the file present in the location by two methods:
1. I degugged the code and stopped at the point where Workbook is ready to be initialized referring the file from the location. I opened and see that the file is opening and the records are present in it. I closed and continued debugging and still the NullPointerException.
2. I hard coded the file location where the xlsx file is already present and yet again the exception happens.

Answer (score 0):

I know I had a similar problem with POI when I received a Resource from a Spring rest service, before saving and then reopening it.

Have you tried the following things?

- Write the file somewhere else. Then read it.
- Use an xls Workbook. Generally I recommend to use `Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(input);` to create your Workbook. One of the great strengths of POI is that it offers the `Workbook` interface to have standardized operations for XLS and XLSX files.

Comment: Hi magicmn, I have updated my code and I still get the same NullPointerException.

Comment: Hi magicmn, I have added the exception details in the main post under update 3. Please see if this helps in further narrowing of the problem. I have also tried by hardcoding reading the xlsx from a different path